# Chat service in heroku doesnt support xhr too

Tags: javascript, heroku, xmlhttprequest

Yo!

```
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
socket = new io.Socket();
```

yo im having a chat application in deployed to heroku and i had done all the config when i send a request to the url i cant get any respond to heroku.. status is just pending but when I try in localhost it would just work properly

Comment: This question to waaaay too broad blud - you'll need to be more specific about your situation before ma homies will check dis question out.